# Does it make sense to add a unique index on an auto-increment column?

Tags: mysql

I do not want to use extra space for a unique-index, Can i use an auto-increment column without having to index it and still get the same performance?

Comment: Whether you get "the same performance" with or without an index depends on the queries you are running.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Mainly Select statements

Answer (score 0):

Usually, an auto-increment column is the primary key of a table -- it is hard for me to think of situations where this is *not* a good idea.  If so, the primary key is already a unique key as well as non-NULL, so no other indexes are needed or desired.

If the column is not the primary key, then you probably do want to declare an index on it for performance.  A unique index would normally be appropriate.